# Filling combobox with years

Tags: javascript, combobox, xpages, formula, lotus-domino

I am working with xpages and i want to fill a combobox with Years starting with 2010.
I tried to do it without success.
Any idea of the formula item to fill to the combobox ?
Thanks

Comment: So show us what did you try :)

Comment: A combobox for XPages (server-side) or a combobox in the browser (client-side)?

Comment: Contrary to the comments made by people that closed this question I believe it is a very valid basic XPages question. If we are to encourage development of the platform we need a place where they can go and ask questions without the embarrassment of having their questions closed. This question does solicit an exact answer as provide below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 parts to it:

- generate the Year numbers
- put it into the combo box

Jeff showed the client side solution, but I suspect you look for a serverside variation
Click on values in the property panel and add a computed item (Serverside JavaScript)

Then simply add:

```
   ["2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"]
```

.. or the fomula that returns the equivalent. To my best knowledge the values need to be String.

**Update**:

```
   var result = [];
   for (i = 2010; i < 2051; i++) {
       result.push(i.toString());
   }
   return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I failed to write the formula that returns values for example from 2010 to 2050 in String.I don't want to enter them manually

Comment: Added the formula. push() and toString() are your friends. Works both in client and on server (to make the array)

Comment: Thanks for your aide.i am a beginner in programming

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="lb"></div>
<script>
function fillCombobox( nbrOfItems ) {
    var opt, x;
    var baseEl = document.getElementById("lb");
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("name","lb1" );
    select.setAttribute("size", "1" );
    for( x=2010; x<=2010+nbrOfItems; x++ ) {
        opt = document.createElement( "option" );
        opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode( x ) );
        select.appendChild( opt );
    }
    baseEl.appendChild( select );
}
fillCombobox( 20 );
</script>
```